# First inventory file is ignored when running ansible-playbook with multiple "-i"s

Tags: ansible

Ansible-playbook seems to ignore the first inventory file when running like following. It recognises only the last file.

Could you advise how to get it run on both servers? I'm running ansible-playbook 2.3.2.0

```
ansible-playbook -i test1.infrastructure  -i test2.infrastructure deploy_server.yml
PLAY [all] *********************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************
ok: [test2]

TASK [Get release package] *********************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using unarchive module rather than running tar

changed: [test2]

TASK [Set latest_sourcetree] *********************************************
ok: [test2]
...
```

Following are examples of the inventory files

test1.infrastructure

```
##################
[test1]
##################
test1hostname
[test1:vars]
# Database
db_server=dbservername
dbschema=test1schema
oracle_sid=test1sid
oracle_port=1521
...
```

test2.infrastructure

```
##################
[test2]
##################
test2hostname
[test2:vars]
# Database
db_server=dbservername
dbschema=test2schema
oracle_sid=test2sid
oracle_port=1521
...
```

deploy_server.yml

```
  - hosts: all
  pre_tasks:
  - name: Get directory name in server release package
    shell: tar -tzf "{{server_release_package}}" | head -1 | sed -e 's/\/.*//'
    register: server_code_dir

  - name: Set latest_sourcetree variable = "{{server_root_dir}}/{{server_code_dir.stdout}}"
    set_fact:
      latest_sourcetree: "{{server_root_dir}}/{{server_code_dir.stdout}}"

  roles:
   - deploy_source_tree
```

deploy_source_tree/tasks/main.yml

---

```
- name: Create directory {{latest_sourcetree}}
  file:
    path={{latest_sourcetree}}
    state=directory

- name: Unpack server release package to {{latest_sourcetree}}
  unarchive:
    src: "{{server_release_package}}"
    dest: "{{server_root_dir}}"
    remote_src: yes

- name: Write runtime properties file
  template:
    src: "{{playbook_dir}}/environments/{{client_id}}/{{env_id}}/files/server.runtime.properties"
    dest: "{{latest_sourcetree}}/conf/server.runtime.properties.{{dbschema}}"

- name: Generate Cshrc file
  shell: cd {{latest_sourcetree}}/conf/ ; ./generate.sh -p server.runtime.properties.{{dbschema}} -b -d -t -o Cshrc.{{dbschema}}

- name: Replace new Cshrc file
...
```

EDITED - @itiic 's suggestion works, put the inventory files in a directory and run with "-i dirname", I'm still curious as to why using multiple -i don't work, if anyone can advise, I really appreciate

Comment: Can you add the content of deploy_server.yml ?

Comment: Sorry, added the file and task file of the role.

Comment: Are you using the same names for the servers? It's possible they're being overwritten: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#using-multiple-inventory-sources

Comment: for 2.5.4 it works, try to put your inventory files to one folder and specify a folder as an inventory.

Comment: @itiic your suggestion works, thank you. I'm still curious as to why multiple -i don't work, if anyone can advise, I really appreciate